# how to parse json object from json in postgres

Tags: json, postgresql

I have one big json object

how can i achieve below sql in PostgreSQL without using table

```
SELECT value->'col1' AS mycolumn
FROM json_object_keys('{"jcol1": "A", "jcol2": "B"}') as value
```

Json is `{"activities-heart":[{"dateTime":"2016-10-17","restingHeartRate":65}}]}`

expected output `heartrate :65`

Comment: Explain "*without using table*".

Comment: What is the expected output? `value->'col1'` doesn't make sense, because in your example `value` is a simple string value (the key of the JSON document) not a JSON document itself

Comment: Are you looking for `SELECT * FROM json_each('{"jcol1": "A", "jcol2": "B"}');`?

Comment: i actually need that jcol1 value as A. I already have one json object and i want to parse that object without table,but json_each gives me everything.but i need only particular value for jcol1

Comment: [edit] your question and add the expected output.

Comment: Thanks your question helped me i.e SELECT '{"jcol1": "A", "jcol2": "B"}'::json->>'jcol1'